# Display empty field in ListView when Datetime in Datatable is 01/01/1900

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a `DataTable dtLeaves` with 5 columns, 2 of those are `DateTime StartDate, EndDate` columns, that may have a minDate value `01/01/1900` and the DataTable displayed through a `ListView LeavesListView`, is there away for the ListView to Display the Dates `01/01/1900` as empty field instead of there actual value?
the DataTable is filled from an SQL Server.

XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="LeavesListView" Margin="10,10,13,10" Background="White" Opacity="0.8" Grid.Row="2" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="14" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" SelectionChanged="LeavesListView_SelectionChanged" MouseDoubleClick="LeavesListView_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="تاريخ البدء" Width="120" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StartDate, StringFormat=yyyy/MM/dd}" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="تاريخ الأنتهاء" Width="120" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EndDate, StringFormat=yyyy/MM/dd}" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="نوع الاجازة" Width="100" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LeaveType}"  Foreground="Red" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

the Code to load the Data into the ListView

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Variables.DtLeaves = DataLoad.LoadData("EmpLeaves", "");
}
private void LoadLeaveData()
{
    try
    {
        if (EmployeesListView.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
        Variables.DtLeaves.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("EmpID = '{0}'",
        Variables.Dt.Rows[EmployeesListView.SelectedIndex][0]);
        Variables.DtLeaves.DefaultView.Sort = " StartDate ASC";
        LeavesListView.ItemsSource = Variables.DtLeaves.DefaultView;
        LeaveData.DataContext = LeavesListView.SelectedItem;
        LeavesListView.SelectedIndex = 0;
        LeavesListView.Items.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Error({0}): {1} ", ex.Message, ex.HResult), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

and Code in DataLoad.Cs

```
public static DataTable LoadData(string tableName, string filterString)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(Variables.ConString))
    {
        var table = new DataTable("");
        con.StatisticsEnabled = true;
        if (filterString != "")
            filterString = string.Format(" WHERE {0}", filterString);
        Variables.CmdString = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} {1}", tableName, filterString);
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(Variables.CmdString, con);
        var sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(table);
        Variables.CurrentStatistics = con.RetrieveStatistics();
        return table;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a converter:

```
public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly DateTime s_defaultDate = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
        return date == s_defaultDate ? string.Empty : date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView x:Name="LeavesListView" Margin="10,10,13,10" Background="White" Opacity="0.8" Grid.Row="2" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="14" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" SelectionChanged="LeavesListView_SelectionChanged" MouseDoubleClick="LeavesListView_MouseDoubleClick">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:DateConverter x:Key="DateConverter" />
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="تاريخ البدء" Width="120" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StartDate, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="تاريخ الأنتهاء" Width="120" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EndDate, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="نوع الاجازة" Width="100" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LeaveType}"  Foreground="Red" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. ty.

Comment: Just one Edit on the line `<GridViewColumn Header="تاريخ البدء" Width="120" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EndDate, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>` its should be `<GridViewColumn Header="تاريخ البدء" Width="120" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StartDate, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>` i miss wrote it in my question

Comment: @Eng.RedWolf: Fixed.